# How to keep array values in the same column when converting to CSV

Tags: javascript, arrays, join

I'm trying to convert Object values to CSV but join method separates my array values into different columns in Excel. Any idea on how can I avoid this?

The function:

```js
window.downloadCsv = function(records) {

    console.log(records);

    const array = [Object.keys(records)].concat(records);

    console.log(array);

    let result = array.map(it => {

        let objectValues = Object.values(it);
        for (let i = 0; i < objectValues.length; i++) {
            if (Array.isArray(objectValues[i])) {
                //Keep it as array
            }
        }

        return objectValues;
    }).join('\n');

    console.log(result);

    let hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
    hiddenElement.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(result);
    hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
    hiddenElement.download = 'records.csv';
    hiddenElement.click();

};
```

Possible records input:

```
id: "5e8468e2db05ff589ca61b30"
title: "Example Application Number 1"
status: "Preparing Documents"
principalInvestigator: "Mr. Harry Styles"
coInvestigators: ["Niall Horan, Liam Payne, Zayn Malik, Louis Tomilson"]
partners: null
funder: "EPSRC Standard research"
researchGroup: "MedEng"
scheme: "Travel Grant"
requestedAmount: null
estimatedAmount: 1234
submissionDate: "2020-03-23T00:00:00.000+01:00"
startDate: "2020-03-29T00:00:00.000+01:00"
estimatedDuration: null
endDate: null
facility: null
comments: null
dateCreated: "2020-04-01T12:11:46.783+02:00"
lastUpdated: "2020-04-01T12:11:46.783+02:00"
dateDeleted: null
__proto__: Object
```

Current output of result:

```
id,title,status,principalInvestigator,coInvestigators,partners,funder,researchGroup,scheme
5e8468e2db05ff589ca61b30,Example Application Number 1,Preparing Documents,Mr. Harry Styles,Niall Horan, Liam Payne, Zayn Malik, Louis Tomilson
```

Desired output:

```
id,title,status,principalInvestigator,coInvestigators,partners,funder,researchGroup,scheme
5e8468e2db05ff589ca61b30,Example Application Number 1,Preparing Documents,Mr. Harry Styles,[Niall Horan, Liam Payne, Zayn Malik, Louis Tomilson],Apple,Microsoft,XresearchGroup,YScheme
```

It is may easier to understand it in Excel format.
Currently, it looks like this after exporting: https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3cMN.jpg

And the desired look would be: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJG0j.jpg

So, pretty much I would like to keep array values in the same column rather than separating them into different ones which shifts all other columns as well in the `CSV`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to always set up a minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Here is mine:

The most important part is this:

```
const headers = Object.keys(records).join(',')
const values = Object.values(records).map(child => {
    if (child instanceof Array){
      //return child.join('; ');
      const str = JSON.stringify(child).replace(/"/g, "'");
      return `"${str}"`;
    }else{
      return child;
    }

}).join(',')

const result = [headers, values].join('\n')
```

Where we take the keys and the value and put them each in an array and then put them in one array and join them with a new line `[headers, values].join('\n')`

Inside the map you can do either this:

```
const values = Object.values(records).map(child => {
    if (child instanceof Array){
      const str = JSON.stringify(child).replace(/"/g, "'");
      return `"${str}"`;
    }else{
      return child;
    }

}).join(',')
```

Which makes the array string show up in Excel like this:

```
"['Niall Horan','Liam Payne','Zayn Malik','Louis Tomilson']"
```

Or you can do the map like this:

```
const values = Object.values(records).map(child => {
    if (child instanceof Array){
      return child.join('; ');
    }else{
      return child;
    }

}).join(',')
```

And then the output in Excel is like this (semicolon is not read as a column separator unless you use that locale - i.e. German locale):

```
"Niall Horan; Liam Payne; Zayn Malik; Louis Tomilson"
```

```js
const recordObj = {
  id: "5e8468e2db05ff589ca61b30",
  title: "Example Application Number 1",
  status: "Preparing Documents",
  principalInvestigator: "Mr. Harry Styles",
  coInvestigators: ["Niall Horan", "Liam Payne", "Zayn Malik", "Louis Tomilson"],
  partners: null,
  funder: "EPSRC Standard research",
  researchGroup: "MedEng",
  scheme: "Travel Grant",
  requestedAmount: null,
  estimatedAmount: 1234,
  submissionDate: "2020-03-23T00:00:00.000+01:00",
  startDate: "2020-03-29T00:00:00.000+01:00",
  estimatedDuration: null,
  endDate: null,
  facility: null,
  comments: null,
  dateCreated: "2020-04-01T12:11:46.783+02:00",
  lastUpdated: "2020-04-01T12:11:46.783+02:00",
  dateDeleted: null
}

downloadCsv(recordObj)

function downloadCsv(records) {

    //console.log(records);
    const headers = Object.keys(records).join(',')
    const values = Object.values(records).map(child => {
        if (child instanceof Array){
          //return child.join('; ');
          const str = JSON.stringify(child).replace(/"/g, "'");
          return `"${str}"`;
        }else{
          return child;
        }
        
    }).join(',')
    
    const result = [headers, values].join('\n')
    //console.log(headers);
    //console.log(values);
    console.log(result);

    let hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
    hiddenElement.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURI(result);
    hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
    hiddenElement.download = 'records.csv';
    hiddenElement.click();

}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you very much this works like a charm! Greatly explained!

Comment: Great glad to hear!

Answer (score 1):

Try to convert an array to string and then replace commas with another separator, semicolon for example - this way csv interpretator won't split values in array and will count it as single item

```js
let records = {id: "5e8468e2db05ff589ca61b30",
title: "Example Application Number 1",
status: "Preparing Documents",
principalInvestigator: "Mr. Harry Styles",
coInvestigators: ["Niall Horan, Liam Payne, Zayn Malik, Louis Tomilson"]}


    const array = [Object.keys(records)].concat(records);

   let result = array.map(it => {

        let objectValues = Object.values(it);
        for (let i = 0; i < objectValues.length; i++) {
            if (Array.isArray(objectValues[i])) {
               objectValues[i]= objectValues[i]=(`[${objectValues[i].join(';')}]`).replace(/,/g, ';')
            }
        }

        return objectValues;
    }).join('\n');

    console.log(result);
```

Comment: Also, a really nice solution, thank you! So the problem was with Excel interpreting "," as a single item indicator, therefore separated everything into different columns

Answer (score 0):

I would personally suggest changing your solution a bit. You don't need to concatenate keys and values, it makes the `.map()` unnecessarily complicated. Here's what I would do:

```
var keys = Object.keys(records);
// we take the array of values, but we transform any array
// in a string of values separated by +
var values = Object.values(records).map(record => {
    if (Array.isArray(record))
        return record.join("+");
    return record;
});

// Now we can just put everything together
var result = keys.join(",") + "\n" + values.join(",");

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Hi, this works really well, however it still puts array items in separated columns in CSV.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The names of the coInvestigators will be separated by a + instead of a comma, so they are effectively in the same column by any CSV standard. Excel should keep them together with their + signs, and if it doesn't, you should be able to tell him that the data is comma-separated.

Comment: Hm, for some reason it is not, even though this also looks like a good solution, it seems like it needs the replace function as in the answers above to replace the "," separator with anything else. Thank you for your answer though!